# authenticate a user in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How to authenticate a user(model) in django?
according to django docs we can use below method for authenticate users,

```
        user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request,user)
            return redirect('/profile')
```

i had tried above, it success,but it works only for built-in user models that comes with admin panel.
my problem is:

i had created a model(Customer) in models.py with custom fields,ex.phone number

```
from django.db import models


class Customers(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email=models.EmailField()
    password=models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

signin.html

```
<form action="/login/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
  
    
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email">
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

In views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        email= request.POST.get('email')
        password= request.POST.get('password')
        user = Customers.authenticae(email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            user.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/profile')

    return render(request,'login.html')
```

when i tried this, it says:

```
type object 'Customers' has no attribute 'authenticae'
```

do i need to create authenticate() function in models.py, or there is a method for this?  how to authenticate my customer,i just started learning django framework, anyone helps me to achieve this.

Comment: `auth.authenticate`, not `Customer.authenticate`, but it will not work, you will need to register a custom authentication backend as well to work with an email address.

Comment: Spelling of authenticate...?? Please correct and check... Also check this link for reference... https://medium.com/@bsurajbh/django-custom-user-authentication-a6e5ac7ed84

Comment: Also instead of `Customers(models.Model)` you need to inherit from either `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser`.

Comment: @praveenkumar: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#customizing-authentication-in-django

Comment: @Willem Vn Onsem ok, sir i will read,  why you don't write an answer, it helps me,

Answer (score 0):

Builtin User class has authenticate method. To use authenticate method you have to link your Customer model to builtin User model.

There are three ways to link your Model to Builtin User Model:

1. You can [extend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) Customer from Builtin User Model.
2. You can [override](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model) builtin User Model.
3. Easiest way is to [inherit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) from AbstractBaseUser.

Here is a full [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing is to extend the user model or create a new one entirely.

Plus, if you must authenticate using email, then you have to write your own authentication back-end.